# JQuery :focus when the browser ain't focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

Without considering the performance, I always tough the jquery object returned by `$(":focus")` would be equivalent to `$(document.activeElement)`.

However, if you're breaking into browser debugger and evaluate `$(":focus")`, you won't get any element while `$(document.activeElement)` will still return the focused element.  I was thinking about some kind of observer effect issue but the same is also true if you set the focus outside the browser.

According to [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/), the focus selector should "*Selects element if it is currently focused*".  As there's no mention about the browser focus, I was wondering if this was the expected behaviour or if it should be reported as a bug.

If you want to try this behaviour, I created a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xyg6j6jp/5/) example.  You'll see text how `$(":focus")` reacts when you'll focus away from the input (within the form, in the console or in an other application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the source for the `:focus` selector:

```
"focus": function( elem ) {
    return elem === document.activeElement
        && (!document.hasFocus || document.hasFocus()) 
        && !!(elem.type || elem.href || ~elem.tabIndex);
}
```

So in order for the element to be returned, `elem` must equal the `document.activeElement`, the document must have focus, and the element must have a `type`, `href`, or `tabIndex` property.

The two are not equivalent

---

**edit**

In your fiddle when you remove focus from the input, `document.activeElement` becomes the `body`, and it doesn't matter whether or not the document has focus.

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: in [sizzle's source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/external/sizzle/dist/sizzle.js)

Comment: I just updated the fiddle example to be more specific about the focus

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here [CSS :focus Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp)

> The :focus selector is allowed on elements that accept keyboard events or other user inputs.

And `document.activeElement` can contain any or almost any element from the page

Comment: css doesn't have anything to do with this